# Any array update function,will return the whole modified array after update at specified index?

Tags: ruby

I need one help.

```
[1,2][-1] = 44
#=> 44
```

The above is fine. But I am looking for a direct function which will do 
such update on the specified index of any array and will return the 
whole modified array. Is it possible? any inbuilt function there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the original object, using `tap`:

```
[1,2].tap { |array| array[-1] = 44 }
=> [1,44]
```

If you are going that far though, there might be prettier ways to do this. E.g.

```
class Array
  def set_item index, value
    self[index] = value
    self
  end
end

[1,2].set_item( -1, 44 )
=> [1,44]
```